# convert list into random list within list python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Let us imagine that in python we have list of numbers, like this:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What is the simplest possible way to convert this list of numbers into a random series of lists within lists?

Like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4], 5, 6, [7, 8], 9]
```

Comment: Does it have to stay "sorted"?

Comment: `2` is missing in your input? or you add it in output list?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`random.randint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
import random

def random_series(lst, size=3):
    start = end = 0
    n = len(lst)
    while end < n:
        end += random.randint(1, size)
        if end - start == 1:
            yield lst[start]
        else:
            yield lst[start:end]
        start = end
```

Example usage:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(random_series(lst))
[[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7], [8, 9]]
>>> list(random_series(lst))
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(random_series(lst))
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
>>> list(random_series(lst))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, [8, 9]]
```

Comment: +1. Please review my answer too and let me know if it's okay.

Comment: @ComputerFellow duplicating your comment. :)

Comment: @ComputerFellow, `rand_series` in your code modify the original list. That could cause issue depend on situation.

Comment: @ComputerFellow, the function also does not preserve order. But OP does not specified that; it may not be a problem.

Comment: @falsetru wow. thanks. I'll see if I can make it any more elegant!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Your code is basically similar to mine. (except you used `list.append` while I used generator function (`yield`)).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, BTW, `if len(x) == 1:` can be replaced with `else:`. And `L2.append(x[0])` with `L2.extend(x)`.

Comment: @falsetru yes but I am trying to understand how to change `size` ?

Comment: @falsetru Yes I think because I am slicing `L[l: l + r]` so `x` can't be of `0` length and I should use else with extend. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I chose `3` because the maximum length of the sublist in the question is 3.   If you mean how to pass `3` to `random_series`: `random_series(lst, 5)` or `random_series(lst, size=5)`

Answer (score 0):

My Code (I am assuming `2` is in input list):

```
from random import randint

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print L
l, length = 0, len(L)
L2 = []
while l < length:
    r = randint(0, length - l)  # rnum < length_remaining  
    x = L[l: l + r] # taking next `r`  numbers from original L 
    if len(x) > 1:   
        L2.append(x)  # append as list        
    if len(x) == 1:
        L2.append(x[0]) # append as single element 
    l += r    
print L2
```

Some execution:

```
$ python  x.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9]
$ python  x.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
$ python  x.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8], 9]
$ python  x.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6], [7, 8], 9]
```

Not very much but a bit improved:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print L
l, length = 0, len(L)
L2 = []
while l < length:
    r = randint(1, length - l)  # rnum < length_remaining  
    x = L[l: l + r] # taking next `r`  numbers from original L 
    if len(x) > 1:   
        L2.append(x)  # append as list        
    else:
        L2.extend(x) # append as single element 
    l += r    
print L2
```

Comment: If some one find mistake(s) please add a comment also. that will be helpful for me.